# How to use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging in NOT ASP.NET dotnet core applications

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core

There are a lot of examples code about logging in ASP.NET dotnet core application using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`.

But how I can write logs to file using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` in NOT ASP.NET application - dotnet core library or console application?

Comment: You can use some logging framework like [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/), [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) amongst many [others](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt694089.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I use log4net.  It is simple to configure and use and allows you to distinguish between logging for: Debugging, errors etc.

You can install it using Nuget.

The configuration in the web.config/app.config would look something like this:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="C:\MyApp\log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] %method %stacktrace - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
```

Here the logs are saved to: C:\MyApp\log.txt

Then put this in your Application_Start method:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Then in your code do this:

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;

public class MyClass 
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));

public void MyMethod()
{
  try
  {
      //Do something e.g. connect to database
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    log.Info(e.ToString());
  }
}

}
```

Have a look here for more information: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: @DmitryRomashov You will easily find extensive tutorials and docs about log4net. Just google it. Tutorials are off-topic for SO.

Comment: @Dmitry Romashov, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @w0051977 Cmon guy, I asked about dotnet core applications, not full .NET framework. I want to know how to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` stuff and so on.

Comment: @Dmitry Romashov, you edited your question 13 minutes ago.  I answered the question 32 minutes ago.

Comment: @DmitryRomashov If you want to use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging you should have stated that in the question in the first place. Now you got a very elaborated answer and you get impatient? Really? Usually questions that show such a great lack of research effort are closed in the blink of an eye ...

Comment: @Dmitry Romashov, based on your updated question; this may help you more: https://stackify.com/net-core-loggerfactory-use-correctly/